# Собрать в массив текст по шаблону из всех постов текущей категории в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-query

Заранее извиняюсь, если терминология повергнет вас в шок, я не программист!

Задача - найти во всех постах текущей категории текст, совпадающий с шаблоном **постоянное начало текста - произвольная середина текста - постоянное окончание текста**, выкинуть начало и окончание, выкинуть повторы и поместить оставшиеся уникальные значения в массив в алфавитнои или другом порядке, посчитать количество уникальных элементов массива и вывести все результаты.

**постоянное начало текста** и **постоянное окончание текста** могут быть тэгами HTML.

Например, в разных постах встречается **я *плохо* программирую**, **я *ужасно* программирую**, **я *отвратительно* программирую**, **я *безобразно* программирую**.

На выходе должно получится что-то вроде

> Я программирую 4 разными способами: безобразно, отвратительно, плохо и ужасно

Я более-менее справлюсь с сортировкой массива, подсчётом количества его элементов и, возможно, смогу избавиться от дубликатов и заменить последнюю запятую на "и".

Но я не знаю, как наполнить массив. Нужна ваша помощь. Спасибо заранее.

---

Если вкратце, в содержании каждого поста есть такой текст:

> Пост 1: `я <i>плохо</i> программирую` и `я <i>безобразно</i> программирую`
>
> Пост 2: `я <i>плохо</i> программирую` и `я <i>отвратительно</i> программирую`
>
> Пост 3: `я <i>ужасно</i> программирую` и `я <i>ужасно</i> программирую`
>
> Пост 4: `я <i>безобразно</i> программирую`, `я <i>плохо</i> программирую` и `я <i>отвратительно</i> программирую`
>
> Пост 5: `я <i>безобразно</i> программирую`, `я <i>безобразно</i> программирую`

Все посты внутри одного раздела (текущего), которым и надо ограничить поиск.

В массиве должно остаться только `безобразно`, `отвратительно`, `плохо` и `ужасно`, т.е. - только уникальные значения.

Если выяснится, что я программирую еще и потрясающе и это в последствие будет указанно в каком-либо посте внутри данного раздела и совпадать с заданным шаблоном, `потрясающе` тоже должно добавиться в массив.

Comment: У вас данные нерегулярные. В 4 постах за начало можно взять "программирую и я", а в 5 такого нет. Любой код зависит от данных. Вы уж сформулируйте, что вы хотите четко. А вот у вас тексте вопроса одно, в комментариях какие-то `<li`, которых в вопросе нет.

Comment: И приведите в порядок синтаксис. А то у вас закрывающие теги `i` не отличаются от открывающих.

Comment: Правил текст на скорую руку. Все данные на рабочем сайте регулярные (нерегулярных данных в моём примере я тоже не нашёл, кроме пары тэгов, которые забыл закрыть), все открывающие тэги - открывающие, все закрывающие - закрывающие. Сейчас поправлю более вдумчиво. Спасибо, что заметили. Строка `sort( array_unique( $excerpts ) );` в Вашем скрипте не несет никакой нагрузки, массив не чистится; поменял на `$excerpts = array_unique( $excerpts );`, чтобы все дубликаты исчезли. Но массив, по-прежнему, наполнен только первым попавшимся в тексте совпадением с шаблоном, остальные совпадения игнорируются.

Comment: Я полностью признаю, что мои навыки написания кода нулевые, в отличие от Ваших, но в данном случае речь не про `array_unique`, а про `sort`. `sort( array_unique( $excerpts ) );` в моём конкретном случае не работает, работает `$excerpts = array_unique( $excerpts );`. Давайте не будем переходить на личности.

Comment: Да я и не переходил на личности. А с array_unique вы правы. Ошибка в том, что sort принимает массив по ссылке, ему надо отдать переменную. Поправил код, вместо одной строчки теперь две.

Comment: Но код по-прежнему, выбирает в массив только первое попавшееся совпадение в каждом посте, все остальные совпадения игнорируются. Получается так, что если в каждом посте я в первую очередь отзываюсь о себе, как об **ужасном** программисте, массив будет заполнен значением **ужасный**

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78105/discussion-between-ykky-and-kagg-design).

Answer (score 0):

Такой код я поместил в файл 834283.php в корне темы:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: 834283
*/

$start    = 'начало';
$end      = 'конец';
$excerpts = array();

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => - 1,
    'category_name' => 'blog',
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    /** @var WP_Post $post */
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $content = $post->post_content;

    $pos = mb_strpos( $content, $end );
    if ( false === $pos ) {
        // $start not found
        continue;
    }

    $pos = mb_strpos( $content, $end );
    if ( false === $pos ) {
        // $end not found
        continue;
    }

    $content = explode( $start, $content )[1];
    $content = explode( $end, $content )[0];

    $excerpts[] = $content;
}

$excerpts = array_unique( $excerpts );
sort( $excerpts );

echo 'Count=' . intval( count( $excerpts ) ) . "\n";
foreach ( $excerpts as $excerpt ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( $excerpt ) . "\n" );
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Код создаёт шаблон 834283, который я назначил [странице](http://test.kagg.eu/so834283/) на тестовом сайте.

В коде делается выборка по записям категории [blog](http://test.kagg.eu/category/blog/). Для каждой записи проверяется наличие строк `$start` и `$end`. Если есть - делается выборка между ними и результат заносится в массив `$excerpts`.

Потом проверка на уникальность, сортировка и вывод.

Comment: Очень близко, но не совсем. Ваш код заполняет массив первым найденным значением и выводит его столько раз, в скольких постах оно встречается, подсчитывая по тому же принципу.

Comment: Да ладно, что вы мне сказки рассказываете. Создал еще одну запись и blog (7). Код не менял. Посмотрите на страницу результатов.

Comment: У меня нет цели рассказывать вам сказки, мне нужно, чтобы работало ). Извините, если мой ответ выглядел обидным. Но Ваш код, скопированный без изменений, кроме замены **начало** и **конец** на тэги HTML `$start    = '<li>';` и `$end      = '<';` выдаёт именно тот результат, о котором я сказал выше. Возможно, дело в треугольных скобках. Я вообще не шарю в том, что пытаюсь сделать, поэтому ценю любую помощь, и вы мне уже здорово помогли ответом, но, к сожалению, у меня работает так, как работает.

Comment: У вас контент такой, что надо по-другому задавать выборку, т.е. переменные start  и end. Покажите сайт

Comment: Не могу показать - он у меня на компьютере в ВампСервере. Сейчас поправлю изначальный вопрос с примерным содержанием каждого поста в разделе. Я был не слишком подробен, мой косяк )

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'я плохо программирую, я ужасно программирую, я отвратительно программирую, я безобразно программирую.';
$pattern = '/(я\s)(.*?)(?=\sпрограммирую)/iu';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str, $matches);

$phrase = sprintf("Я программирую %s разными способами: ", count($matches[2]));
sort($matches[2]);

$data = array_merge([$phrase], $matches[2]);

$res ='';
$delim = ', ';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

    if (count($data) - 2 == $i)
        $delim = ' и ';

    $res .= $i > 0 ? $data[$i] . $delim : $data[$i];
}

echo rtrim($res, $delim);
```

Comment: Проблема именно в том, чтобы вместо жестко заданного `$str = 'я плохо программирую, я ужасно программирую, я отвратительно программирую, я безобразно программирую.';` был динамически наполняющийся массив, состоящий из найденных совпадений по заданному шаблону во всех постах текущей категории (рубрики), из которых оставлены только уникальные.

Answer (score 0):

Не сидев, сложа руки, пока остальные решают мои проблемы, перерыв массу мануалов и примеров, сделал вот такое:

```
$category_name = $categories[0]->name;

$args = array('numberposts'   => -1, 'category_name' => $category_name);
$posts = get_posts( $args );

foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    if (strpos($content, '<the_tag>') !== false) { // Чтобы избежать ошибки, если пусто
        $dom->loadHTML($content);
        $items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('the_tag');
        }
    for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i ++) {
        $results_array[] = $items->item($i)->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

$results_array = array_unique($results_array);
sort($results_array);

$quantity = count($results_array);

echo $quantity;

foreach ($results_array as $key => $val) {echo $val . "<br />";}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

День потратил, зато сам! ))

Этот код делает ровно то, что мне нужно, но обрамлением искомого может быть только определённый тэг HTML.

Мне достаточно, но идея с обрамлением из обычного текста мне тоже кажется привлекательной, поэтому буду искать дальше - думаю, нужно пристальнее порыть `DOMDocument`. Если кто-то может помочь - приму помощь с благодарностью, потому что написание кода совершенно не мой конёк.

Пользуясь случаем, хочу попросить разбирающихся проверить то, что я наворотил на правильность и оптимальность.

Comment: Возможно, что код делает то, что вам нужно. Но он делает совсем не то, что описано в вопросе. 1. В вопросе ни слова о том, что искомых вхождений может быть несколько. 2. В вопросе ни слова о том, что если их несколько, то все их надо включить в массив. 3. Ваш код не работает с вопросом - в приведенном примере постов нет тегов `<the tag>`. 4. Код вообще непонятно на что заточен, потому что тегов `<the tag>` в природе не существует.

Comment: Вы меня пугаете )) 1. Читайте вопрос. 2. Читайте вопрос. 3-4. `the_tag`  - любой тэг, на какой хотите, на такой и меняйте (the - определённый артикль, tag - тэг), мне показалось, что все найдут очевидным, что `the_tag` - заглушка, на место которой нужно подставить свой тэг.